# Magento 2: How to get custom attribute value in new template

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, product-attribute, template, custom-attributes

I need to get the value of a custom attribute on the product page, as I want to display different sizechart per attribute. For this reason, I have created the following .phtml to get the value of the attribute:

```
File: /app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/sizechart.phtml

<?php 
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('sizechart2');
?>
```

And I have called this file from:

```
File: /app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/sizechart.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

But when I go to product page show the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null**

What is the problem? :(

Thanksss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template is getting value from the Block class as you've mentioned in the xml.

`Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` does not have any product instance.

In your xml you can simply modify your xml by the below

```
File: /app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/sizechart.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Note:** I have changed from `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` to `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`

Comment: Thanksss!!! I did not know that it took the value of the class of the block. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

Create attribute1.phtml file and call all your attributes inside that file.

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attribute1.phtml
```

Add your attribute code.

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getAttributeCode(), 'attribute_code'); ?>
```

Inside your xml file,

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml


<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="attribute1" template="product/view/attribute1.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

after that move your attribute1 block where ever you want.

for example,

```
<move element="attribute1" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
```

Thanks....

Comment: Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Please mark as correct if its working for you.

Comment: I try Rinto George solution because is easier, sorry.

Comment: Ok no worries @IvannVerano

Comment: Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> try this it will help you.

```
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_product = $block->getProduct(); 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) 
{
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

    $data = explode(',',$_product->getData('your_attribute'));
    if(count($data) > 1)
    { 
        foreach($data as $key => $value):                    
            $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute');
            if ($attr->usesSource()): 
                $option_value = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
                echo $option_value;
            endif;
        endforeach;
    }
}
```